# displaying <select> options after inserting record without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am starting to learn AJAX, as of now I already know how to insert data with ajax.. I want to learn how to display the data after inserting without refreshing the page.

here's my form code:

```
<form>
<select class="input" id="Factory_Name" name="factory">
<option value='---' selected>---</option>

<?php
    $qry = $handler->prepare( "SELECT * FROM factory_list WHERE flist_compid = ?");
    $qry->execute(array($id));

    while($row = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $f_id = $row['flist_id'];
            $f_name = $row['flist_name'];
            echo "<option value=$f_name >$f_name</option>";
    }
?>

</select>
<input type="button" id="save_hidden" value="Save New Factory" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
</form>
```

here is the ajax script:

```
<script>
    $('input#save_hidden').on('click', function(){
        var factory = $('input#Name_of_Factory').val();
        var factory_address = $('input#Factory_address').val();
        var factory_country = $('#country option:selected').val();
        var factory_city = $('input#city').val();
        var factory_cperson = $('input#contact_person').val();
        var factory_cnumber = $('input#contact_number').val();
        var factory_email = $('input#email').val();

             //ajax call
                    $.ajax({
                        url     :   'php/savefactory.php',
                        type    :   'POST',
                        async   :   false,
                        data    :   {
                                        buttonsave:1,
                                        factoryname : factory,
                                        address     : factory_address,
                                        country     : factory_country,
                                        city        : factory_city,
                                        contact     : factory_cperson,
                                        number      : factory_cnumber,
                                        email       : factory_email
                                        },
                        success: function(result){
                                        alert(result);                                  
                                    }
    });
       // clear fields after inserting
        $('input#Name_of_Factory').val('');
        $('input#Factory_address').val('');
        $('#country').val('---');
        $('input#city').val('');
        $('input#contact_person').val('');
        $('input#contact_number').val('');
        $('input#email').val('');
    });
    </script>
```

Here is my savefactory.php file

```
<?php
session_start();


if (isset($_SESSION['email'])){
$data = $_SESSION['email'];
include('config.php');
$qry = $handler->prepare( "SELECT id FROM login WHERE email = ?");
$qry->execute(array($data));

while($row = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $id = $row['id'];
}

if(!empty($_POST['factoryname']) && !empty($_POST['address']) && !empty($_POST['country']) && !empty($_POST['city']) && !empty($_POST['contact']) && !empty($_POST['number']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){
        $factory = $_POST['factoryname'];
        $factoryadd = $_POST['address'];
        $country = $_POST['country'];
        $city = $_POST['city'];
        $contact = $_POST['contact'];
        $contact_number = $_POST['number'];
        $emailadd = $_POST['email'];
        //execute sql query
        $qry = 'INSERT INTO factory_list (flist_compid, flist_name, flist_address, flist_country, flist_city, flist_contact, flist_cnum, flist_email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
        $qry = $handler->prepare($qry);
        $qry->EXECUTE(array($id,$factory,$factoryadd,$country,$city,$contact,$contact_number,$emailadd));



            if($qry){
                echo "New Factory Details has been Saved!";
            }else{
                echo "Error Saving the New Factory";
            }
}else{

    echo"Please fill in all fields for factory details";
}

}
?>
```

thank you very much!

Comment: You need to provide your **savefactory.php** file and also tell us where do you want to display the returned values.

Comment: As shown in the first code, I looped through the database to get the all data required and display them inside the <select> tag as <option>.

what I want to achieve is when I add another record, the inserted record should be displayed inside the <select> element as an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to display the data after inserting without refreshing the page

Your `#save_hidden` button is supposed to submit the form in default way. You should use `preventDefault()` to submit the form using AJAX, without refreshing the page:

```
$('input#save_hidden').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // ...
    $.ajax({
        // ...
    });
});
```

To append newly created record to select element, use AJAX `success` callback to determine whether the record has been successfuly stored in DB or not:

```
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        success : function(result){
            // check whether the record has been successfuly stored in DB:
            if(result == 'New Factory Details has been Saved!'){
                // append option to #Factory_Name select:
                var new_factory = $('#Name_of_Factory').val();
                $('#Factory_Name').append('<option value="'+new_factory+ '">'+new_factory+'</option>');
                // clear form fields after inserting:
                $('#my-form').find('input').val('');
            }
        }
    });
```

**NOTE**. Don't clear the form fields before `success` callback.

---

BTW. There's [**`serialize()`**](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method availalbe in jQuery, so no need to extract each form element value separately. Add `id="my-form"` attribute to your `<form>` and then use:

```
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        data : $('#my-form').serialize()
        // Or without using id selector, selialize the form where the submit button is
        //data : $(this).closest('form').serialize()
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

As philip1000 said, you are firing off the default method you will need to prevent the default before you can render the ajax data in the page.

```
$('input#save_hidden').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
```

I'm not sure exactly what you had in mind on how to display the data. However you can simply append the information that you sent by ajax to the DOM when the success function fires.

Here's an example to display the information in a table.

First you could create a table underneath your form, which is hidden by default.

```
<html>
   <table id="complete-table">
        <tr>
            <th>factory name</th>
            <th>address</th>
            <th>country</th>
            <th>city</th>
            <th>contact</th>
            <th>number</th>
            <th>email</th>
       </tr>

    </table>

</html>
```

Then when you've successfully sent off your ajax hook into the success return function, show the form and append your data to it.

```
 success: function(result){

          var tableRow = '<tr>';

          tableRow += '<td>'+factory+'</td><td>'+factory_address+'</td><td>'+factory_country+'</td><td>'+factory_city+'</td><td>'+factory_cperson+'</td><td>'+factory_cnumber+'</td><td>'+factory_email+'</td>';

          tableRow += '</tr>'

          $('#complete-table').append(tableRow);

          $('#complete-table').show();
 }
```

Hope that helps you out.

Thanks

Comment: can I use this method to display a specific column in the database?
I want to display it inside the <select> tag as an <option>..